# Scope minibuffer history to specific Counsel commands

Tags: completion, minibuffer, ivy

If I run `bookmark-jump` and use invoke `M-p`, it cycles through the history of bookmarks specifically. If I run `counsel-bookmark-jump`, `M-p` cycles through the generic minibuffer history, which is more or less useless. How can I ensure that minibuffer history is scoped to specific counsel commands?

Comment: @Drew That's exactly it. Would you like to promote your comment to an answer? I'll happy accept it.

Comment: Done...........

Comment: There's a PR to fix this now: https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/pull/1698

Comment: The aforementioned PR has now been merged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Counsel uses `completing-read` then the call to that function just needs to specify a history variable that is specific to the given command, as parameter `HISTORY`.